# Passing value containing ' in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobilefirst-adapters

I need to pass few values via url the format looks like this

```
example.com?params=['abc', 'xyz', 123456789]
```

Now the issue is I have some values that contains ' abc's like for example

```
example.com?params=['abc's', 'xyz', 123456789]
```

now if i pass this via url,  url thinks abc and s are 2 different value and gives me error as its looking for , after '
url encoding is not a solution tried that because all it makes is %27 for ' and same issues occurs inside function. How can this be done.

Comment: You have to escape those values like `\'`

Comment: Check out [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: That worked. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the comma syntax. And usually when you pull from the querystring you do not need to have typing since everything comes as a string.

example.com?params=abc%27s,xyz,123456789

And I am not sure about the function you are using to pull the querystring but do not forget.
decodeURIComponent()

If this does not help which function are you using to pull from the querystring?